# Get text from ElementRef?

Tags: angular, angular5

Feels like this should be a pretty basic question...

I'm using a plugin that returns a DOM node / element that is NOT visible / rendered. I'm able to convert it easily to an ElementRef, with the nativeElement correctly populated.

How do I get the text of the element?

I know with AngularJS, I would do `angular.elem(node).text()`

Answer (score 22):

To get the text content of the element, use the [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or the [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) property:

```
elementRef.nativeElement.textContent
elementRef.nativeElement.innerText
```

An example is shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrmlfd).

---

Here are some of the differences between them, as given in [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

> - While textContent gets the content of all elements, including `<script>` and `<style>` elements, innerText does not.
> - innerText is aware of style and will not return the text of hidden elements, whereas textContent will.
> - As innerText is aware of CSS styling, it will trigger a reflow, whereas textContent will not.
> - Unlike textContent, altering innerText in Internet Explorer (up to version 11 inclusive) not only removes child nodes from the element,
>     but also permanently destroys all descendant text nodes (so it is
>     impossible to insert the nodes again into any other element or into
>     the same element anymore).